# Autolayout center multiple elements in a row

Tags: ios, storyboard, autolayout

I have 2 labels and 1 imageView in the same row and I want to keep the three centered for all layout sizes, how can I achieve that using autolayout ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do:

- create a view and insert the two labels and the imageView in there
- align that view as you wish
- align the left of the left label to the left of the view
- align the right of the right label to the right of the view
- align the top of the imageView to the top of the view
- align the bottom of the imageView to the bottom of the view
- align the left of the imageView to the right of the left label
- align the right of the imageView to the left of the right label
- align the vertical centers of the imageView and both labels
- set the dimensions of the imageView

left label:
[image]

right label:
[image]

imageView:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Storyboard to download: https://mega.nz/#!LQYhlTZa!2p81W8YsrrHmeG7eWmxjqImJ7f144UOtvztw_HHsfng

Comment: thanks for the answer should I put the labels and image in another subview ?

Comment: @uahakan you have your main view of the view controller and in there you create a new view (the light red one) where you add in your label and imageView. I included a link to the storyboard to download and try out

Answer (score 0):

Embed the 2 labels and the image in another view. Then make that view centered within the superview (horizontally centered).

Comment: I actually did that, the image in the post is the one you suggested. When the screen size get bigger also the subview resizes so the elements in it will lose the center.